# Whatsapp Web QR code not loading on Chrome/Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, google-chrome, whatsapp

I am trying to use the service https://web.whatsapp.com/ on Chrome/Firefox on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Dual boot Windows 8.1). But the QR code that needs to be scanned by the Whatsapp mobile app is not loading. QR code loads perfectly fine on Chrome on Windows 8.1 and others systems having Ubuntu, without any glitch.

I have tried re-installing both Chrome and Firefox from scratch, and both are in latest versions available.

What could be the possible reasons for this error and how can it be fixed?

Update:
This is how it looks on Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ian2u.png
Chrome Version 41.0.2272.76 (64-bit):
Firefox 36.0 
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Answer (score 6):

If you are behind a proxy, it helps to remove the socks proxy configuration.

To do this in Ubuntu 16.04 (and if I remember correctly is exactly the same in Ubuntu 14.04), just go to "System Settings" -> "Network" -> "Proxy", and delete (left in blank) the socks server line and left port in 0.

You don't need to apply this -system wide-, just in the user you want to authenticate in Whatsapp Web.

Once you are done with Whatsapp Web Authentication, you can restore your previous socks proxy settings.

Comment: It worked for me. Im using a authenticated proxy, and after removing the SOCKS proxy the web.whatsapp.com worked.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was dealing with the same problem (QR code not getting loaded in chrome, firefox, WhatsApp application on the laptop) in my laptop having window 8.

what I did was;
in control panel--> internet properties/options--> connection--> LAN settings--> untick box "use a proxy server for your LAN" is written.
save changes; and restart chrome or WhatsApp.
by this method, my QR code got loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This applies if you had it working but failed suddenly. For this it is important to know that the client in the browser is a software for its own (web.whatsapp.com).
From time to time the client in the browser is updated and might not be compatible with the prior versions. I could solve it by remove the registered device within WhatsApp. Removing all cookies and cached data might be important as well.

1. Remove your device registration in WhatsApp
2. Clear cookies and cached data
3. Restart your browser
4. QR should load now and new registration is possible

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the problem like below:
WhatsApp web loaded QR after some time, but when i scanned it showed " couldn't be connected"

Then i removed all linked devices and tried

Now its logged in

Answer (score -1):

Use incognito mode, it has worked for me