# Whatsapp Web QR code won't scan

Tags: websites, whatsapp

Unlike [this questioner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594695/whatsapp-web-qr-code-not-loading-on-chrome-firefox-on-ubuntu-14-04), my WhatsApp Web QR code loads fine, but it won't scan on my Android phone. It's as if the phone doesn't "see" the QR code.

I've done it from my phone in Windows on the same laptop, so I know it's not a problem with the phone.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using Firefox 57.0.4.

Any suggestions?

---

### UPDATE

I've tried it with Chrome and Chromium, and the same problem occurs.

---

### UPDATE

I downloaded a QR Code scanning app, and was able to scan the QR code just fine. So it's a problem with WhatsApp not recognising that the QR code has been scanned.

If you're interested, here's what you get when you scan the QR code:

[image: WhatsApp web QR code scanned successfully]

Comment: It can't be a Ubuntu problem either. A QR code is something shown in a webpage, works in any browser and is OS independent. Do you have the correct screen resolution set / proper graphics drivers installed, if applicable, in Ubuntu? If the page looks the same as in Windows you probably have everything right.

Comment: I've contacted WhatsApp support. Let's see if anything good comes of that (lol)

Comment: I can link 2 of my PC's running Windows 11 to WhatsApp using my phone, but I cannot link WhatsApp using Ubuntu Mate on Chromium. The QR code appears on the browser, but WhatsApp doesn't recogise it. It's not only on Ubuntu that this is happening, it's also happening on Chrome and Microsoft Edge on my Samsung Galaxy S 7+ and Samsung Galaxy S6. It doesn't appear to be related to the browser, but rather the operating system. I will follow this up with WhatsApp and post their reply here.

Comment: @TonyBaynes were you able to solve this?